# Setting a radio button with .prop() is not triggering event handler

Tags: jquery

I have a JavaScript function that listens for a change on a `Radio button` in order to execute the next batch of code.  However, I find that when I physically click the button, it's different from setting it in code (through `.prop("checked",true);`). Why when I change which radio button is selected through `.prop()` does it not trigger the event handler `.change()`?  How can I adjust my code so that the handler hears the change?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oL0r2x20/) that demonstrates the problem

Click the `Radio buttons` and the value will appear in a `div` below. However, when you click the "change to blue" button it will reset the `Radio button` to the "blue" option but the value will not be updated in the "output" div.

HTML:

```
<div id='colors'>
    <input type="radio" id="black" value="Black" name="myRadio" /><label for="black">Black</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="blue" value="Blue" name="myRadio"/><label for="blue">Blue</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="green" value="Green" name="myRadio"/><label for="green">Green</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#changeRadio').click(function(){
     $("input:radio[id='blue']").prop("checked",true);
});

$('#colors input').change(function(){
    var selected_item = $(this).val()
    $('#output').html(selected_item);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just changing the state of the `Checkbox` and not trigger an event on the object; you need to do something that triggers event and changes the state at the same time.

Change:

```
$("input:radio[id='blue']").prop("checked",true);
```

To:

```
$("input:radio[id='blue']").trigger('click');
```